# Starting d3 force-layout collapsed, text labels duplicating

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

My goal is to start the layout with all the nodes collapsed, on click they expand. The issue here is that text labels create duplicates on mouseover. They also create duplicates on the top left of the screen.

I've reduced the json to a minimal amount for testing, which is below the block of code.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Force-Directed Graph</title>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

circle.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

line.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var w = 960,
    h = 500,
    node,
    link,
    root, 
    t;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .on("tick", tick)
    .size([w, h]);

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

d3.json("test.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  update();

 function toggleAll(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
      toggle(d);
    }
  }
    // Initialize the display to show a few nodes.
  root.children.forEach(toggleAll);


update(root); 
});

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
        .charge(-1000)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .friction(0.5)
      .start();

  // Update the links…
  link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links.
  link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  // Exit any old links.
  link.exit().remove();

  // Update the nodes…
  node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
      .style("fill", color);

  // Enter any new nodes.
  node.enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r",  "15")
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)     
      .call(force.drag);

  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();

  t = vis.selectAll("t.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
      .style("fill", color);

  // Enter any new nodes.
  t.enter().append("svg:text")
      .attr("class", "t-node")
      .attr("dx", "25px")
      .attr("y", 0)
      .text("test");
     // .call(force.drag);

  // Exit any old nodes.
  t.exit().remove();

}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

  t.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; }); 
//  t.attr("transform", function(d) {
 //       return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; } ) 

}

// Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

// Toggle children on click.
function mouseover(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update();
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}
function toggle(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

    {
 "name": "Test",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "cat 1",
   "children": [
    {"name": "subcat 1-a", "size": 1082},
    {"name": "subcat 1-b", "size": 1082}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "cat 2",
   "children": [
    {"name": "subcat 2-a", "size": 1082}
   ]
  }  
 ]
}
```

Comment: The key is that you need to modify the data structures that you pass as nodes and links to the force layout instead of passing in new data structures. So keep the list of links and nodes and add to/remove from that instead of recomputing it in your `update` function.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, is there a code based example you know of that demonstrates this?

Comment: There are a few on the D3 examples page, [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347) for example.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I have no idea what I'm looking at in that example. I have a nice collection of examples that relate to the tree diagram but it seems to work differently with the force layout.

Comment: I've made some progress. The load state is now correct. The problem now is that the text labels seem to create duplicates when the mouseover function is called. Here is the full code: (same json)

Comment: Your selector "t.node" doesn't look right. In any case, you should be able to use the same `.enter()` selection you've used for the nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of stealing @Lars' answer, `vis.selectAll("t.node")` looks like it needs to be `vis.selectAll(".t-node")`. If you don't use a selector in `selectAll` that matches the nodes you append in the `.enter()` selection, you'll get duplicate nodes every time it runs.